# How can I see which devices are used by a process?

Tags: process, io, device

`iotop` and `iostat` are great tools to see how much I/O is happening.
But I haven't found out how these (or other) tools can show me the I/O rate per device and per process.

So I'm looking for a way to let `iostat` show the specific processes or to let `iotop` show the I/O per device when limited to one process. Or another tool that can give me insight into which device is used by a process.

I need this to get a better grip on optimizing MySQL on a box that has Fusion I/O cards but it's still very slow.

Answer (score 1):

for example 
`iostat /dev/sda1`

should already give you "per device", or rather per partition statistics

so you need to figure out your fusion I/O cards device name and just add it as an option.

`iostat 5 2 /dev/sda1` for example shows you the statistics on partition 1 on the device sda for "since boot" and for the last 5 seconds 
see the manual for more details ( `man iostat`)

for further breakdown on per process base use for example iotop.

see [serverfault similiar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/212661/determining-which-process-is-causing-heavy-disk-i-o)

additionally you might want to read more about getting a bit more specific info here:

[Blog from Benjamin Cane](http://bencane.com/2012/08/06/troubleshooting-high-io-wait-in-linux/)

Comment: I've taken a look at `man`. `iostat /dev/sda1` only shows me the I/O of the device, but it doesn't show me which process(es) was causing that I/O.

Comment: see my edit, it should help you there aswell.